# How can I tell if a given Linux system has GPGPU capabilities?

Tags: rhel, hardware, gpu

I am using a remote virtual machine (administered by my company), running Red Hat Linux, to do some fairly heavy Engineering number-crunching type work, using the commercial analysis software package ANSYS. I know that ANSYS has support for using a GPGPU to help accelerate the calculations (there is an option to enable/disable it). However, I am wondering how I can tell if the virtual box I am using has GPGPU capabilities and, if so, what those capabilities are?

Is there some way I can query this in the system, or test it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with GPGPUs, so I'll leave this as a comment. The `lspci` command should show you the make and model of the graphics card on an RHEL system.

Comment: @Haxiel ok, thanks for your input. So, how can I then tell if that graphics chip can be used as a GPGPU? I assume that might depend to some extent on the driver, and whether the Linux driver for that chip supports it?

Comment: I believe you'll need to look up the card on the respective vendor's website. As I understand it, not all graphics cards can run in a GPGPU configuration. I don't know if it's possible to check this information from the system itself. From the site, you're likely to get the appropriate tools or SDKs. Nvidia cards are specifically addressed by [this solution article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/19540).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few implementations of GPGPU. Among them you have the two most extended ones: [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) (non-profit, supported by Intel and AMD) and NVIDIA's [CUDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA).

If you have either of the GPU cards that support the feature, you *could* try to enable the guest access to the GPU. Although you will probably need root permissions at the host level and configure the hypervisor.

If you have an Intel or AMD supported card, you can install [clinfo](https://github.com/Oblomov/clinfo) and it should report the OpenCL capability.

There are plenty of articles about GPGPU in CentOS, RHEL, Debian with KVM, if that is your virtualization manager. For ex. here is an official article by [NVIDIA regarding GPGPU and CUDA for RHEL KVM or RHV/RHEV](https://docs.nvidia.com/grid/latest/grid-vgpu-user-guide/index.html#red-hat-el-kvm-install-configure-vgpu).